# NSInvalidArgumentException unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios

I am working on a twitter viewing application and having an issue with getting the data to pass from the cell to the detail view. Everytime I click the cell my program terminates with this error.

```
2015-09-04 12:18:34.298 twitterView2[10580:872508] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TwitterPostInfo objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f9fb261f890'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010527fc65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000104f18bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001052870ad -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001051dd13c ___forwarding___ + 988
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001051dccd8
```

Comment: When posting, you should format code using the curly braces.

Comment: My apologies. Thank you for correcting my posting, I am very new to stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to find the location of the problem is in xCode go to the breakpoint navigator (Command + 7). Click the + at the bottom and select "Add Exception Breakpoint". Now when you run your program it will stop when the exception occurs and show you the stack trace instead of the "uncaught exception"

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know for sure without seeing where you're assigning the tweetDetail property of this class, but it would appear that you're assigning an object of type TwitterPostInfo, not NSDictionary.  Check where you're setting this property and be sure it's the correct type.

Alternatively, if you are intending to pass a TwitterPostInfo object, you'll have to change the type of tweetDetail to match.  Of course, you'll have to update how you access its data (I am assuming it's a custom class.  I could not find anything via Google).

EDIT:

After seeing your prepareForSegue method, my guess is that you're intending to pass along a TwitterPostInfo object, not an NSDictionary.  If this is true, you'll want to change tweetDetail's type from NSDictionary to TwitterPostInfo.  Then, instead of using `[self.tweetDetail objectForKey:@"text"]` and `[self.tweetDetail objectForKey:@"created_at"]`, you'll want to use something equivalent to `self.tweetDetail.text` and `self.tweetDetail.createdAt` depending on how you structured your class.

Try this for TwitterDetailVC.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TwitterPostInfo.h"

@interface TwitterDetailVC : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) TwitterPostInfo *tweetDetail;

@end
```

and this for TwitterDetailVC.m's viewDidLoad method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tweetTextLabel.text = self.tweetDetail.tweetText;
    self.tweetTimeLabel.text = self.tweetDetail.timeDate;
}
```

Comment: everywhere that I have used tweetDetail is in the code that I have posted above. All the objects I am pulling are strings. It is a custom class

Comment: Surely you must be assigning the tweetDetail property from somewhere.  If not, why would you be fetching data from it in viewDidLoad?  Could you show me how you're passing data to this class?

Comment: I am still new to programming but the data is being passed in the segue is it not?

Comment: Right, in the prepareForSegue method you can get a reference to your destination view controller and assign any exposed properties, such as your tweetDetail property.  What I'm suggesting is verifying that the object you're assigning is an NSDictionary because your error suggests that it is in fact a TwitterPostInfo object.  Since you're using segues, could you edit your original post to include the prepareForSegue code from the view controller which instantiates your TwitterDetailVC class?

Comment: Great, thanks.  So it looks like you have an array of twitter posts and you're grabbing the one you selected from a tableView to pass to your TwitterDetailsVC.  That's all fine.  It looks to me like the array probably contains TwitterPostInfo objects.  Can you confirm if this is true?  If so, you should change the type of tweetDetail from NSDictionary to TwitterPostInfo.  It might also help if you shared the TwitterPostInfo.h file, or at least its properties, in your original post.